# spring data JPA CriteriaBuilder.isNull return syntax error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Specification:

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Hotel> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    Predicate predicate = root.get("starRating").in(s);
            if (unrated) {
                predicate = cb.or(predicate, cb.isNull(root.get("starRating")));
            }
     return predicate;
}
```

Where `s` is a `Set`.

SQL log:
`Hibernate: select hotel0_.hotel_id as hotel_id1_16_, hotel0_.star_rating as star_ra13_16_ where hotel0_.active=? and (hotel0_.star_rating in () or hotel0_.star_rating is null) order by lower(hotel0_.hotel_name) asc`

Error:
`ERROR 6828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"`

Exception:
`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue in your query is here: `hotel0_.star_rating in ()`.
Put an empty check on set s before this point:

```
if(s != null && !s.isEmpty()){
  predicate = root.get("starRating").in(s);
}
```